# Communicate between 2 lighting web components in a visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components

I know it is possible to include a lightning web component into a VisualForce page. It's also possible to include multiple lightning web components into a VisualForce page. Though, I cannot find a way to `fireEvent` and `registerListener` so that I can pass data between 2 lightning web components included in my VisualForce page.

I've tried by importing the following

`import { currentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';`

But this is returning me an exception, that the currentPageReference should have an `@wire{currentPageReference} pageRef` property. Which makes sense as we cannot access the lightning in VisualForce

I've also created my own pubsub module, which works ok when using in the lightning experience builder. So communication between the two components is working on lightning pages.

Any tips or hints on this topic?

Code to show what I have tried:

Fire event...

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";
import { registerListener, unregisterAllListeners, fireEvent } from "c/xxx_pubsub";

export default class xxx extends LightningElement {

    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
    @api searchInput;

    handleProductSearch(event) {
        this.searchInput = event.target.value;
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, "startSearch", this.searchInput);
    }
}
```

Listener...

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { registerListener, unregisterAllListeners, fireEvent } from "c/xxx_pubsub";

connectedCallback() {
    // Some method which is called
    registerListener("startSearch", this.getSearchResult, this);
}
```

Thank you

**Update on this topic**

As Salesforce-sas suggested, I'm using the lightning messages service.

One component is using the following code.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import productsChannel from '@salesforce/messageChannel/SearchProductsChannel__c';

export default class xxx extends LightningElement {

    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

    handleProductSearch(event) {
        // Read the data which we'll use and store in variable
        payload = { searchInput: event.target.value };

        // "Publish data in our channel"
        publish(this.messageContext, productsChannel, payload);
    }

}
```

The other component, which should receive the data is as follows:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getSearchResult from '@salesforce/apex/xxx.getSearchProdDetails';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, MessageContext, APPLICATION_SCOPE } from 'lightning/messageService';
import productsChannel from '@salesforce/messageChannel/SearchProductsChannel__c';

export default class xxx extends LightningElement {

    searchInput;
    filterCriteria = null;

    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;
    @wire(getSearchResult, {searchInput: '$searchInput'}) searchResult ({error, data}) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else if (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }

    subscribeToChannel() {
        console.log("here 2");
        if (!this.filterCriteria) {
            this.filterCriteria = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                productsChannel, 
                (message) => this.handleMessage(message),
                { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
            );

            console.log(this.filterCriteria);
        }
    }

    unsubscribeToChannel() {
        unsubscribe(this.filterCriteria);
        this.filterCriteria = null;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("here");
        this.subscribeToChannel();
        //this.getSearchResult('SearchString');
    }

    getSearchResult(searchInput){
        console.log(searchInput);
        if(searchInput !== undefined){

            // Stringify the search input
            let searchInput = JSON.stringify({
                searchString: 'SearchString'
            });

            // Call the method
            getSearchResult({searchInput:searchInput}).then(result => {
                if (result && result['productList']) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        this.unsubscribeToChannel();
    }

    handleMessage(message) {
        console.log('biep');
        this.searchInput = message.searchInput;
    }

}
```

Further help is really appreciated.

Currently when right before the lwc gets injected to the DOM, I see some calls are being triggered. Though I don't get inside the handleMessage method.

Also, when firing the event `handleProductSearch` I don't see anything happening on the other component.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) - GA from summer 20

> Use Lightning message service to communicate across the DOM between
> Visualforce pages, Aura components, and Lightning web components,
> including components in a pop-out utility bar.
>
> Use the Lightning message service functions to communicate over a
> Lightning message channel.

Comment: I've tried to implement it, but until now without success. I'll update my question.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans the org you are testing on - is it on summer 20?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce documentation: Communicate Across the DOM can be done via 2 ways: `Lightning Message Service` and `pubsub` Module.

Reference: [Communicate Across the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_pubsub)

Comment: The pubsub module needs a `@wire(currentPageReference) pageRef` property. When being on a VisualForce page, I cannot access the `lightning/navigation` module and read this pageReference. I'm using the `Lightning Message Service`